# Console returning [Object object] instead of object members

Tags: javascript, object

I was trying to build myself a small function to simpifly logging to the console in JavaScript. But for some reason it doesn't log the properties of the object, only the type of the logged object ([Object object].

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

var randomObject = {

    fistname:"peter"
};

function log(message,color){

    var color = color || "green";

    console.log("%c" + message, "color:" + color + ";font-weight:bold; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'");

}

log(randomObject);
```

i'm grateful for any help/explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting an `object` to a `string` by doing concatenation,

```
"color:" + color .....
```

When you attempt to do so, the `primitive` value of the `object` will be returned and concatenated with the target string.

If you want to print the object in a string format then use `JSON.stringify(color)`.

```
console.log("%c" + message, "color:" + JSON.stringify(color) + ";font-weight:bold; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'");
```